# Calling two functions with select onchange to pass a variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I use a function `createVariable()` to create the variable `$user_rank` to use it in the second function `getRank()`.
I am calling the two functions using a dropdown:

```
<select name="rank" onchange="createVariable(this.value); getRank();">
```

**createVariable()**

```
function createVariable(user_id) {
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "file1.php",
       data: "user_id=" + user_id,
       success: function(result){
           $("#TargetRank1").html(result);
       }

    });
}
```

The seconde function (in `file1.php`) use this variable `$user_rank`

**`getRank()`**

```
function getRank(){
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "file2.php?user_rank=<?php echo $user_rank; ?>",
       success: function(result){
         $("#TargetRank2").html(result);
       }
    });         
};
```

**Problem**

When I use the dropdown for the first time and I choose the `user1`, I get only the info from the function `createVariable()`. When I use it again and choose the user2, the function `createVariable()` returns the info of the user2 (Good), but the function `getRank()` returns the info of **user1**.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: the function `getRank` needs to get the value from `createVariable` - call it from within the `success` callback in `createVariable`

Comment: @RamRaider. Thank you. I thought about that, but the two functions are not in the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be due to the createVariable() ajax call is not completed before the getRank() function is called. So getRank() gets old data. try using async false

```
function createVariable(user_id) {
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "file1.php",
   async: false,
   data: "user_id=" + user_id,
   success: function(result){
       $("#TargetRank1").html(result);
   }

});
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much. It works, but I've noticed that the dropdown freeze a little bit before het shows the data.
Is there another way to do that?